# Angular JS return data from service and Http callback Method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Created a Angular JS service, which sends request to the server for the JSON data. I am able to receive the data correctly in the service, but i am unable to return data to the controller. Please check as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>The content is {{content}}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('MyService', function($http) {
    this.sendRequest = function() {
     $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/json'
  }).then(
   function successCallback(response) {
    console.dir('This is the response');
       console.dir(response);
       return response;
   }, function errorCallback(response) {
       console.dir('This is the error');
       console.dir(response);
       return response;
     }
    );
    };
    this.addition = function(a,b) {
     return a+b;
    }; 
});

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    console.dir(MyService.addition(4,5));
    var a = MyService.sendRequest();
    console.dir("Main program " + a);
    $scope.content = a;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

For the addition function, i am able to get data correctly (I mean, it is returning sum of 4+5), but coming to the "sendRequest" method, it is invoking the $http call in this method and getting back to the caller "null/empty" data without waiting for the $http method.

Problem is, $http call in the "sendRequest" method is asynchronous (I mean, "then" is called once it is getting the response from the server) and i want to wait for the server response and send response to the caller.

Comment: `sendRequest` doesn't return anything... You can return a promise and handle it in the controller.

Comment: @elclanrs do you mean like this, return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/json'
  });

Comment: Yes, then in the controller do the `.then` and inside do `$scope.content =`

Comment: @elclanrs I tried that, it is working, but i want the service to gather the response and send it back to the caller (I didn't want to return promise for each and every call, then write success and error methods for each call). Is their any other way.

Comment: @user3278897 no, that's the way to work with async tasks, by now. You can take a look at async and await on ES7 but just for curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

Your service should be look like this,

```
app.service('MyService', function($http) {
    this.sendRequest = function() {
        // You should return $http's result
        // $http will return a promise
        return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/json'
        }).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                console.dir('This is the response');
                console.dir(response);
                return response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.dir('This is the error');
                console.dir(response);
                return response;
            }
        );
    };
    this.addition = function(a,b) {
        return a+b;
    }; 
});
```

Now modify your controller like this,

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    console.dir(MyService.addition(4,5));
    MyService.sendRequest().then(function success(data){
       // here you will get your server data
       var a = data;
    }, function error(){

    });
    console.dir("Main program " + a);
    $scope.content = a;
});
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the `errorCallback` will result in a resolved (successful) promise. It should be `return $q.reject(response)`

Comment: @Abhilash then what is the need of callback functions two times, i mean, why you are using "then" two times, once in the service and other time near the caller. Cannot we just return the    return $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/json'
        }) and write the then function once. More over, as i said in the comment that i already tried this and working fine by taking the advice of the elclanrs.

Comment: @Phil is right. In your `errorCallback` you are **converting** a rejected promise to a fulfilled promise. In `errorCallback` you should either `throw response;` or `return $q.reject(response)`.